# Is there a python function to catch UDP traffic a machine is forwarding

Tags: python-3.x, networking, udp

I am running a system with the following configuration:

NODE A   <->   PROXY   <->   SWITCH   <->   PROXY   <-> NODE B

Where node A and its proxy share a common private network, node b and its proxy share a common private network, and the proxy's are connected to the switch.

I have configured each as such:

```
#nodeA     
#!/bin/sh
#Aliases
alias ip='sudo ip'
alias iptables='sudo iptables'


#interfaceconfiguration
ip link set enp0s8 up
ip addr add 192.168.0.1/29 dev enp0s8

iptables -t nat --flush

sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.2 enp0s8


iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

---

```
#proxy a
#!/bin/sh
#Aliases
alias ip='sudo ip'
alias iptables='sudo iptables'

#interfaceconfiguration
ip link set enp0s8 up
ip link set enp0s9 up
ip addr add 192.167.0.1/26 dev enp0s9
ip addr add 192.168.0.2/29 dev enp0s8

sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat --flush

sudo route add default gw 192.167.0.2 enp0s9
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/29 via 192.168.0.2 dev enp0s8

iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

---

```
#proxy B
#!/bin/sh
#Aliases
alias ip='sudo ip'
alias iptables='sudo iptables'

#interfaceconfiguration
ip link set enp0s8 up
ip link set enp0s9 up
ip addr add 192.167.0.2/26 dev enp0s9
ip addr add 192.168.0.10/29 dev enp0s8

sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat --flush

sudo route add default gw 192.167.0.1 enp0s9
sudo ip route add 192.168.0.8/29 via 192.168.0.10 dev enp0s8

iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
```

---

```
#node B
#!/bin/sh
#Aliases
alias ip='sudo ip'
alias iptables='sudo iptables'

#interfaceconfiguration
ip link set enp0s8 up
ip addr add 192.168.0.9/29 dev enp0s8

iptables -t nat --flush

sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.10 enp0s8

iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

I then have this simple server client code running on NODE A and NODE B just to have some traffic going through the network:

```
import socket
import sys
#NODE A - SERVER
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.1', 10000)
sock.bind(server_address)

while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print(data.decode())
```

---

```
import socket
import sys
#NODE B - CLIENT
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.1', 10000)


while True:
    sock.sendto(input("Message to send:").encode(), server_address)
```

My question is, how can I, at the proxy level intercept these messages to bring them up to the application level so that I can work with them as to add a layer of encryption for example then send them back out to their destination so that the proxy on the other side can decrypt the message.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly good debugging loop:

```
while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print(data.decode())
```

Once you see that the right datagrams are arriving,
that loop will be a natural place to forward datagrams
to your favorite destination.

Ensuring that your listening socket was properly bound can be a tricky thing,
given that you have several addresses and interfaces to worry about.
Consider using `$ sudo tcpdump -i en0 udp port 10000` to examine
datagrams in flight, before you even run that debugging loop.
You can use the command on the sending host,
on an intermediate transit host,
and on the destination host.
By viewing `$ ifconfig -a` you may find that an interface besides `en0`,
perhaps a tunnel interface, is relevant for reading the packets you're interested in.
Once you *know* certain packets are flowing,
that tends to make it easier to correctly specify the `bind()` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong way around. Namely, if you want to "work with" packets on the proxy, then you don't want to be telling the kernel to do any IP level forwarding

the Linux tun/tap interface would let you do this, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283801/90376) for an example of how this is used with a VPN.  although there are [Python packages](https://pypi.org/project/python-pytuntap/) that help if you really want Python code to be doing the work

as a minor side note, I've generally found it an anti-pattern to put `sudo` onto basically every line of a script as you have.  I'd just run the entire script via `sudo` and just have the code in it assume this is the case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! After discussion this morning I realize now that you are right I do not want my nodes to be aware of the proxy. The solution we came up with was to bind each proxys adapter on a node side to all other node address's in the network, and keep all the nodes in the same network. Therefore the proxys receive all the data and it can then be routed to the proper proxy for the proper node.